# Getting a List of Categories in Middleman

Tags: ruby, middleman

Say I have categories 'a', 'b', ... of some currently unknown number. Without going through and manually saying which categories there are, would it be possible to find each category and basically make an array where each element contains the name of the category? I know that it's possible to find the category of an article page that is currently being visited using current_article.data.category, but I'm not sure about any other methods of using the category.

Comment: This isn't too clear, I would show some code to explain the data structures involved.

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% pages = sitemap.resources
     categories = Array.new
     for page in pages do
        categories.insert(1, page.data.category)
     end
     categories = categories.uniq
 %>
```

I believe this is one way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `helpers/categories.rb` file:

```
def generate_categories
  sitemap.resources.map { |res| res.data.category }.uniq.sort
end
```

Restart the Middleman dev server.

Then use it like this:

```
<% categories = generate_categories %>
```

PS I didn't actually try it. My solution is based on the assumption that your solution is valid.

Comment: This is the method I use also - but I use blog.articles so I can name the required blog also it also.

    blog( 'portfolio' ).articles.map { | r | r.data.category }.uniq.sort